# Value from TextBox\Combobox to Range

Tags: excel, vba

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = "G4"

Set CodeRange = Range(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
```

Gives: `methog range of object _global failed`

Pls some help how to convert value from form to range.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in that line? What happens if you refer to a workbook, rather than just Range etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks okay to me, although slightly unorthodox. Have you dimensioned CodeRange as a range?

If the activehseet is a chart sheet you will get that error.

You should also fully qualify your reference with the worksheet or activesheet.

```
With WorkSheeets("Sheet1")
    Set CodeRange = .Range(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
End With
```

If your code is residing in the Userform module then you can use the Me keyword instead of Userfrom1.

I prefer to get ranges from the user using a input box like this:

```
Sub HTH()

    Dim rRange As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
            "Please select a range with your Mouse to be bolded.", _
            Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rRange Is Nothing Then
        '// Your code here
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Input boxes are quite limited compared to forms.

Comment: My point was that if the OP is simply trying to get a range from the user then I suggest using an inputbox.

Comment: CodeRange is Range, yes. If i set value and use it in Userform1_Initialize(), it shows mistake. But if i set value in Userform1_Initialize() and use it onclick, all work perfect. Thx for hint with InputBox, i didnt know about it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Decimal sphvalue = Decimal.Parse(cmbo_sph.SelectedValue.ToString());

```
        txt_sph.Text = sphvalue.ToString();
        Decimal cylvalue = Decimal.Parse(cmbo_cyl.SelectedValue.ToString());
        txt_cyl.Text = cylvalue.ToString();
        try
        {
        SqlConnection searchconnnection = new SqlConnection("DataSource=ANI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=divinei;Integrated Security=True");
            searchconnnection.Open();
            SqlCommand searchcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT CL_sphValue,CL_CylValue FROM ConvertCharts where SP_sphValue=" + Decimal.Parse(txt_sph.Text) + " and Sp_CylValue=" + Decimal.Parse(txt_cyl.Text) + " ", searchconnnection);
            searchcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader convertreader = searchcommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (convertreader.Read())
            {
                sphtxt.Text = convertreader[0].ToString();
                cyltxt.Text = convertreader[1].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }`enter code here`
```